# How to get different TableAdapters from data later with one call

Tags: c#, datatable, sqldataadapter

I want to have a fairly generic method that that loops through a datatable to process each record in the table I'm working with.  The TableAdapter and Datatables are strongly typed and are created in the XSD designer.  The datatable can be any one of 6 different actual tables to process.  If I create the tableadapter and datatable within this method, everything works fine...

```
    var eventsToProcessTableAdapter = new NoticesData.CobraNoticesTableAdapters.COBRAEventsTableAdapter();
    var eventsToProcessDataTable = eventsToProcessTableAdapter.GetPDFsToProcess();

        foreach (DataRow currentRow in eventsToProcessDataTable.Rows) {

                     // Do some processing...

                      currentRow[("pdfDate")] = currDateTime;
                      eventsToProcessTableAdapter.Update(eventsToProcessDataTable);

        }
```

However, I don't want to create all the tableadapters and datatables in this method - essentially, I want to call out to the datalayer to get the table that I want to work with.  So, what I'd like to do is move this code to another method and that return the particular event adapter / table combination that I'm working with like so:

```
var eventsToProcessTableAdapter = oRptQuery.getEventsDataAdapter(eventTableName, 0);
var eventsToProcessDataTable = eventsToProcessTableAdapter.GetPDFsToProcess();
```

In the getEventsDataAdapter method, I have a switch statement where I basically want to return the dataadapter for the particular table I am processing.  This way, I don't have to create all 6 dataadapters/tables in the outer method and I can abstract the data creation to the data layer.

```
public SqlDataAdapter getEventsDataAdapter(string evtTable, Int32 empID) {

var eventsDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

... (more code)...

                switch (evtTable)
                {
                    case "EvtCOBRA":
                        eventsDataAdapter = new NoticesData.CobraNoticesTableAdapters.COBRAEventsTableAdapter();
                        break;

... (more code)...
```

However, I am getting a couple of errors when I attempt to do this.  In the generic method, Visual Studio tells me SqlDataAdapter does not contain a definition for GetPDFsToProcess.  In my getEventsDataAdapter method, it says that I "Cannot implicitly convert type NoticesData.CobraNoticesTableAdapters.COBRAEventsTableAdapter to System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter.

I am unable to change the data design, so please suggest alternate solutions without affecting the design of the backend tables.  I've tried using an interface to apply the GetPDFsToProcess() method to the adapter returned by getEventsDataAdapter, but I have been unsuccessful.  So, how can I move the dataadapter creation to another method without creating these errors?

Comment: Does COBRAEventsTableAdapter inherit from SqlDataAdapter?

Comment: It inherits from whatever the Dataset designer configures it to inherit from.  The Baseclass is showing to be System.ComponentModel.Component in the properties window.